# Since upgrading to Access 2013 OutputTo command (to PDF) doesnt work

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have been using my Access (accdb format) database using Access 2010 for three years. I have recently upgraded to Access 2013 since then, the line of OutputTo code (see the bottom of post) doesn't work I get

> The Command or Action OutputTo isn't available now

. I have seen many people have similar (but not the same) problems and none of the suggestions has worked for me.

However, if I launch Access with the Shift key held down the Outputs work perfectly, so I don't think its anything to do with the VBA code (see below) more of a permission problem.

I would be very  grateful for a solution, Thank you

This is my code

```
  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Vehicles Due In", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Cars\Vehicles Due In.pdf", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
```

**UPDATED EDIT: Added code from comments**

```
On Error GoTo Err_cmdReportPreview_Click 
   Dim stDocName As String 
   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Overdue Balances", "PDFFormat(.pdf)", _
     "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Cars\Overdue Balances.pdf", False, "", , _
     acExportQualityPrint DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Vehicles Due In", _
     "PDFFormat(.pdf)", "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Cars\Vehicles Due In.pdf", _
     False, "", , acExportQualityPrint 
Exit_cmdReportPreview_Click: 
    Exit Sub 
Err_cmdReportPreview_Click: 
    MsgBox Err.Description 
    Resume Exit_cmdReportPreview_Click 
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at the permissions on the C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Cars folder? Does running it by holding Shift open it as an Admin user? Maybe you need to add your windows account to the folder?

Comment: I have full control on that folder (same as Admin) It seems to be more permissions within Access when I open Access with Shift held own everything works!

Comment: Pinpoint the cause first - replace  the folder with a local temp folder and see if it works from there. Is there more code before or after that might be relevant? Are you closing the form? Might be a timing thing - Can you add a `Me.SetFocus` before your `OutputTo` command and see if that works

Comment: Also - why are you using the enumeration value `"PDFFormat(*.pdf)"` for the constant `acFormatPDF`? Do you have a problem with that constant being recognized - that would indicate a version issue.

Comment: Another thing looks suspect - did you copy/paste that line of code in - or did you type it in manually? Just wondering if you generate the Google folder name by code based on the `User` - and your constant  `"PDFFormat(*.pdf)"` is missing a space. It helps if we have the real code to work with instead of dealing with red herrings.

Comment: this is the full Sub

Comment: On Error GoTo Err_cmdReportPreview_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
        
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Overdue Balances", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Cars\Overdue Balances.pdf", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Vehicles Due In", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Cars\Vehicles Due In.pdf", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    
Exit_cmdReportPreview_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdReportPreview_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdReportPreview_Click


End Sub

Comment: The Google drive folder is a local folder its synced to my drive by google backup and sync, ive tried putiing timer delays between each OutputTo command made no difference, thing is it works perferctly when I open access withe the Shift key held down

Comment: ill try changing "PDFFormat(*.pdf)" to acFormatPDF see if it helps thank you

Comment: will also try Me.Setfocus

Comment: When you want me to respond to a comment you need to insert my name like @dbmitch otherwise I don't get notifications. I inserted your code into the question - it's unreadable when you put it into comments. How do you access the code with SHIFT key down - do you step thru one line at a time - or run via the same form button click?

Comment: @dbmitch Me.Setfocus did the trick, I'm so grateful thank you. Just to clarify the difference between the output working and not was when I opened Access holding down the shift key to bypass startup actions output worked normal startup they didn't. How do I award you points?

Comment: Thanks for getting back - I'll post it as the answer and you can mark it as such - upvote if you feel it worthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try changing `"PDFFormat(*.pdf)"` to `acFormatPDF` constant - that will let you know if your version supports this method, because it looks like you've missed a space in your string. That constant should evaluate to  `"PDFFormat (*.pdf)"`

The second thing to try is to use `Me.SetFocus` just before the `OutputTo` command. That may explain why it works when you use the  key and not automated. I'm not sure what actions are happening in the form when you click the button vs. running manually with the startup disabled, but you may be forcing it to keep focus.